# find equation of plane.

Tags: calculus

Let

. Show that the curve with parameterization

lies in a plane, and find an equation of the plane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: If you know three points in the plane, you can find the plane, right? Well, plug in $u = -1, 0, 1$ to get three points.

Now that you know what the plane HAS to be, you can show that the entire curve $r$ is contained in it without too much difficulty.

Comment: Thanks for answering. So if I have these 3 points, (a-b+c, ..., ...) (c,c,c) and (a+b+c, ..., ...) then I can show that the curve is contained in the plane by finding its parametric equation using these points?

Comment: Why don't you try doing so and see what happens? When you do that, it's math. Otherwise, it's just copying.

Comment: Edited to include the attempt I made, would it be sensible to change the parameter u in the final equation since its used in the curve r(u)?

Comment: A good start, but you might want to use the *implicit* form of the plane: letting $\mathbf q = \mathbf d \times \mathbf e$, we get that $\mathbf q$ is a normal vector to the plane, which is then defined as the set of all points $\mathbf x$ satisfying $$(\mathbf x - \mathbf c) \cdot \mathbf q = 0.$$

Comment: Now you just need to show that for every values of $u$, we have that $\mathbf r(u)$ satisfies this equation. That may be easiest if you leave $\mathbf q$ written as $\mathbf d \times \mathbf e$ rather than explcitly doing any algebra with the $a$s, $b$s, and $c$s.

Comment: Thanks will try it right now.